# Complex number inequality calculations

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

Let $z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb C$. I hope to show that the quantity $$ 3 | z_1 |^4 + 3 |z_2|^4 + 4 |z_1 |^2 |z_2 |^2 + z_2^2 \overline{z_1} ^2 + z_1^2 \overline{z_2}^2 $$ is nonnegative. Does this hold? I confirmed that $z_2^2 \overline{z_1} ^2 + z_1^2 \overline{z_2}^2 $ is real but not always nonnegative. The overline means the complex conjugate. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:
$$
z_2^2\bar z_1^2 +z_1^2\bar z_2^2 = (z_1^2+z_2^2)(\bar z_1^2+\bar z_2^2)-|z_1|^4-|z_2|^4
$$

Comment: Thank you, then that quantity is always nonnegative.